# Test Class Code coverage Issues

Tags: apex, unit-test, developer-console, developer

I'm writing a test class for my controller and unable to cover some of the lines and now the code coverage is 74%. Can you any one please sugegst how to cover
the lines which are not covered.

[image]

```
        Apex Class:
        --------------
        public class RestViewOnDPT {
            public String dptId {public get;public set;}
            public Debt_Pricing_template__c dpt{public get; public set;}
            public Boolean isSelfSanction {public get; public set;}
            public Boolean showDptPage{public get; public set;}
            public Boolean showDptPageForOwner{public get; public set;}
            public String DptOwnerName{public get; public set;}
            
            public RestViewOnDPT(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
                Boolean isTeamLeader = false;
                showDptPageForOwner = true;
                showDptPage = true;
                Id userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
                dptId = controller.getId(); 
                Debt_Pricing_template__c dpt = [Select Is_New_Template__c,Id,Template_Name__c ,CreatedById, Customer_Name__r.Restricted_View__c,Opportunity__r.Mark_as_Private__c,Opportunity__r.OwnerId,Customer_Name__r.OwnerId, Customer_Name__c,Name_TeamLeader__c,Status__c, Owner.name,Opportunity__c From Debt_Pricing_Template__c where Id=:dptId limit 1];
                List<GroupMember> DptGm = [Select UserOrGroupId, GroupId From GroupMember  where GroupId = '00G20000001QuIn'];
                
                System.debug('DPTGM='+DptGm );
                Boolean isGrpMember= false;
                for(GroupMember  dptGMUser:DptGm )
                {   
                    if(userId == dptGMUser.UserOrGroupId){
                        isGrpMember = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                
                if ('Self Sanction'.equalsIgnoreCase(dpt.Template_Name__c)){
                    isSelfSanction = true;
                }else{
                    isSelfSanction = false;
                }
                List<AccountTeamMember> accTeamMbrList = [select UserId from AccountTeamMember where AccountId =:dpt.Customer_Name__c and IsDeleted = false];
                for(AccountTeamMember accTeamMbr:accTeamMbrList){
                    if(userId == accTeamMbr.UserId && userId == dpt.Name_TeamLeader__c){
                        isTeamLeader = true;
                    }
                }
                
                List<OpportunityTeamMember> oppTeamMbrList = [select UserId from OpportunityTeamMember where OpportunityId =:dpt.Opportunity__c and IsDeleted = false];
                for(OpportunityTeamMember oppTeamMbr:oppTeamMbrList){
                    if(userId == oppTeamMbr.UserId && userId == dpt.Name_TeamLeader__c){
                        isTeamLeader = true;
                    }
                }
                List<Profile> prof = [Select Id, Name From Profile Where Name = 'System Administrator' or Name = 'Barclays: System Administrator' order by Name];
                Boolean isAdmin = false;
                
                if(prof != null && prof.size() == 2) {
                    if(String.valueOf(prof.get(0).Id).equals(UserInfo.getProfileId()) || String.valueOf(prof.get(1).Id).equals(UserInfo.getProfileId())) {
                        isAdmin = true;
                    }
                }
                if(dpt.Customer_Name__r.Restricted_View__c == true && userId!=dpt.ownerId && !isAdmin && userId!= dpt.Customer_Name__r.OwnerId && !isGrpMember && userId!= dpt.Opportunity__r.OwnerId){
                       
                    **<---------------The below all the lines are not covered in Test Class ----------------->**
                    
                    if([select count() from AccountTeamMember where accountid=:dpt.Customer_Name__c and userid=:userId and isDeleted=False]==0) 
                    {
                        showDptPage = false;
                        DptOwnerName = dpt.Owner.Name;
                    }
                    
                    else if(dpt.Opportunity__r.Mark_as_Private__c == true && userId!= dpt.OwnerId && !isAdmin && userId!= dpt.Opportunity__r.OwnerId && !isGrpMember && userId!= dpt.Customer_Name__r.OwnerId)
                    {
                        if([select count() from OpportunityTeamMember where OpportunityId =: dpt.Opportunity__c and userid=:userId and isDeleted=False]==0) 
                        {
                            showDptPage = false;
                            DptOwnerName = dpt.Owner.Name;
                        }
                        if([select count() from AccountTeamMember where accountid=:dpt.Customer_Name__c and userid=:userId and isDeleted=False]==0) 
                        {
                            showDptPage = false;
                            DptOwnerName = dpt.Owner.Name;
                        }
                    }
                    
                } 
            }
        }

        Test Class 
        ----------
        @isTest(seeAllData=True)
        public class RestViewOnDPTTest {
            static testMethod void RestViewOnDPT() {
                test.startTest();

                    User u = [select id,Name from User where Id=:userInfo.getUserID() Limit 1];  
                    Account acc2 = [Select id from account where Global_Parent_Account__c=null  limit 1];
                    Opportunity opp2 = new Opportunity();
                    opp2.Name='Test Opportunity';
                    opp2.StageName='IsWon';
                    opp2.CloseDate=system.Today();
                    opp2.Mark_as_Private__c=true;
                    opp2.ownerId=u.id;
                    insert opp2;
                   
                   Debt_Pricing_template__c dpt2 = new Debt_Pricing_template__c();
                    dpt2.Customer_Name__c=acc2.id;
                    dpt2.Name_TeamLeader__c=u.id;
                    dpt2.Status__c='Approved';
                    dpt2.Opportunity__c=opp2.id;
                    dpt2.ownerId=u.id;          
                    dpt2.Name_TeamLeader__c=u.id;
                    insert dpt2;                
                  System.runAs(u) {
                    GroupMember GM = new GroupMember();
                    GM.GroupId='00G20000001QuInEAK';
                    GM.UserOrGroupId=u.id;
                    insert gm;    
                      
                    AccountTeamMember atm = new AccountTeamMember();
                    atm.UserId =u.id; 
                    atm.AccountId=acc2.id;
                    atm.accountid= dpt2.Customer_Name__c;
                    insert atm;
                      
                    OpportunityTeamMember optm=new OpportunityTeamMember();
                    optm.OpportunityId=opp2.id;
                    optm.UserId=u.id;
                    insert optm;    
                    
                    ApexPages.StandardController standardcontroller2 = new ApexPages.StandardController(dpt2);
                    RestViewOnDPT rvd2 = new RestViewOnDPT (standardcontroller2 );   
                      
                      
                    dpt2.Status__c='Approved';
                    Id userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
                    update dpt2;
                    Debt_Pricing_template__c dptTest = [Select Is_New_Template__c,Id,Template_Name__c ,CreatedById, Customer_Name__r.Restricted_View__c,
                                                        Opportunity__r.Mark_as_Private__c,Opportunity__r.OwnerId,Customer_Name__r.OwnerId, Customer_Name__c,Name_TeamLeader__c,Status__c, Owner.name,Opportunity__c 
                                                        From Debt_Pricing_Template__c where Id=:dpt2.Id limit 1];
                      
                    ApexPages.StandardController standardcontroller3 = new ApexPages.StandardController(dpt2);
                    RestViewOnDPT rvd3 = new RestViewOnDPT (standardcontroller3 );  
                    rvd3.showDptPageForOwner = false;
                    rvd3.DptOwnerName = dpt2.Owner.Name;
                    rvd3.dpt = dptTest;
                  }
            }
```

Comment: You need to make this expression evaluate to true in the data that your test sets up `dpt.Customer_Name__r.Restricted_View__c == true && userId!=dpt.ownerId && !isAdmin && userId!= dpt.Customer_Name__r.OwnerId && !isGrpMember && userId!= dpt.Opportunity__r.OwnerId`. Google `System.runAs` that you will likely need to use.

Comment: @keith C The above condition is covered in code coverage part only after the above condition is fails. How I can refer the after the condition below lines in test class ?

Comment: there should be no reason to use SeeAllData = true let alone hard-coded Ids for Groups.